# show sql query result in html page

Tags: javascript, html, sql

In my javascript I have the following sql query:

```
SELECT City, COUNT(Address) FROM customers GROUP BY City
```

How can I display this table (the result from my query) in the html page??

Thanks,
Monir

Comment: How are you quering the DB using javascript?

Comment: You need to provide more details of what you're querying the database with e.g. PHP, Java, ASP.  You'll get back some kind of Result Set which you'll be able to iterate over and add HTML markup too.  The question needs more info.  Unless you are genuinely querying a database with JavaScript, in which case I'm intrigued.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't query a Database directly from Javascript. You need to have a page (in php, for example) that hits the database(s) and displays the data. Then you can load that page into your current page using AJAX.